# Как связать видимость Html.TextBoxFor с Сheckbox?

Tags: javascript, html, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Есть код на `JS`, который позволять открывать и закрывать доступ к полю input, в зависимости от значения `checkbox`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="form-inline">  
        <div class="checkbox col-md-offset-5">
            <label>
                <input id="check1" type="checkbox" onchange="checkk(this);"/>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3">Email address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text1" disabled="true"> 
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>

<script>
  function checkk(elem) {
    var value = elem.checked;
    if(value == true)
    {
        text1.disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        text1.disabled = true;          
        text1.value = ' ';
    }       
}
</script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь проделать тоже самое и в своем проекте `ASP.NET MVC`

**AddLearner.cshtml**

```
...

                <td align="center">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="checked" onchange="checkk(this);" />
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ElementPlans[i].ValueOge15, new { id = String.Format("text{0}", number++), disabled = false })
                </td>

            </tr>
            }
        </table>
    }

    <script>
        function checkk(elem) {       
            var value = elem.checked;
            if (value == true) {
                text1.disabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                text1.disabled = true;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Но мое поле `text1` в независимости от того как прописано значения атрибута `disabled`

```
disabled = false
disabled = true
disabled = ""
@disabled = false
@disabled = true
или @disabled = ""
```

**всегда остается не доступным**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит?

Comment: У Вас создается несколько элементов с одним и тем же id — text1. Если вы в исходный вариант добавите еще один инпут (или любой другой элемент) c id="text1", то тоже ничего работать не будет.

Comment: @Yaant, ну вообще будет, но только зависит от браузера - как именно :-) и кстати id разные

Comment: @Grundy Разными они стали уже после моего комментария, см. историю правок. :) Насчет зависимости от браузера, согласен, при написании комментария проверял только в Хроме. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я предполагаю, что у вас ошибка происходит в js скрипте, потому что он не может найти объект text1. Должно быть так document.getElementbyId("text1").style.disabled = false